# How to hide actionbar based on layout in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to disable actionBar when the layout is changed for smaller devices but I dont know how to do it. Probably I will do

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

but how to check the layout?

Answer (score 1):

Its simple you can use this example to get the size of the screen and then hide the `ActionBar` if needed.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

it will get you the size of the screen in inches. and if you want it in pixels then you can use

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options in this situation.

Firstly, are you sure that your application will be useable without an action bar? e.g. Why do you need an action bar on large devices when you can do without it on smaller devices?

Are you using the Android [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) (Which I recommend)? If so you can choose not to include the toolbar in your layout for the smaller screen in your layout xml files. e.g. Include the toolbar in `layout-large` directory and exclude it from `layout-small`. Then when you bind the views in your activity/fragment handle the case where the toolbar view is not found.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
if(toolbar != null) {
    //set up my toolbar here which might include
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Another option is to use multiple styles for different size screens. Where for the large screen your style is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and for your small screen its `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best approach is to make a copy of your style.xml of the res/values to the res/values-mdpi (or your desired layout size) and change the AppTheme to your style + .NoActionBar.

Example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which layout was loaded you can add tags to your layout for example:

ldpi layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:tag="ldpi" >
```

mdpi layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:width="match_parent"        
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:tag="mdpi" >
```

and so on.

In your program code you can now check which tag the layout have:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
String tag = layout.getTag();
if(tag != null && tag.equals("ldpi")) {
    // Ldpi Layout loaded, hide actionbar

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DisplayMetrics**

```
 public void setAppInvisible() {
        actionBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       // Or actionBar.hide();

    }

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;

if(screenWidth < 500){
    setAppInvisible();
}
```